# How to distinguish between "for all $x>0$", "on the interval $(0,\infty)$" and "on the interval $[a,\infty)$ for all $a>0$"?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Assume in the following that $x,a$ are real numbers. How do I distinguish between the statements "for all $x>0$", "on the interval $(0,\infty)$" and "on the interval $[a,\infty)$ for all $a>0$"? As far as I can tell, these three sets are the same set, but in my assignment, there seems to be important differences.

For instance in one exercise I want to prove that the series $S(x)$ "converges uniformly on the interval $[a,\infty)$ for all $a>0$". Later I am asked to prove that the same series does not converge uniformly "on $(0,\infty)$". Then later on, the lecturer claims that by picking an arbitrary closed interval $[a,b] \subset (0,\infty)$, and proving some statement about some series on that closed interval, concludes that the statement is true for all $x>0$ since $[a,b]$ is arbitrary.

What is going on? When I am faced with these statements, how should I interpret them? How do I distinguish between these statements and similar statements like them? Which of these statements imply the others? It would be best if you could generalize away from examples involving series.

Comment: If, for any $a>0$, $S(x)$ converges uniformly on $[a,\infty)$, then, in particular, $S(x)$ converges for any $x>0$, so there is some confusion there...

Comment: $[a,\infty)$ is talking about a *family* of sets while $(0,\infty)$ is one specific set. These sets have different properties (e.g. the former is closed while the other is open) which affect how functions behave on them. One shouldn't think that $a\to 0$ implies $[a,\infty) \to (0,\infty)$ (in some sense) and that properties on $[a,0)$ should carry over. As you found out, uniform convergence is one such property which does not carry over.

Comment: Convergence vs. Uniform convergence.  The former is about "points" and latter about "sets".  When we say a series converges on a set, we really mean (confusingly perhaps) that it converges "at each point of that set."  Then things can get more complicated when we say "a series converges uniformly on each set $E$ in some collection of sets $\mathcal E$."  Just be careful to distinguish between "at a point" and "on a set"  in these two statements and use precision of language rather than rough intuition to keep things straight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key here is to observe that although
$$
\bigcup_{a>0} [a,\infty) = (0,\infty)
$$
the two statements

- $(S_n)_n$ converges uniformly on $(0,\infty)$
- $(S_n)_n$ converges uniformly on $[a,\infty)$

are **not** equivalent. Namely, the first implies the second, but there are cases (as, apparently, yours) where the second holds but not the first.

To see why, let us look at what the first statement means:

> $(S_n)_n$ converges to (the function) $S$ uniformly on $(0,\infty)$: $$\sup_{(0,\infty)} \lvert S_n(x)-S(x)\rvert \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0$$

while the second statement says

> Fix any $a>0$. Then $(S_n)_n$ converges to (the function) $S$ uniformly on $[a,\infty)$: $$\sup_{[a,\infty)} \lvert S_n(x)-S(x)\rvert \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0$$

Can you see the difference? It is the same sort of difference as in saying "for any fixed $a>0$, $\ln$ is bounded on the interval $[a,1]$" vs. "$\ln$ is *not* bounded on $(0,1]$".

---

Now, I assume the last part is something like showing that $S$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)$, "since all $S_n$'s are and you have uniform convergence on every $[a,\infty)$." The subtlety here is that while you don't have uniform convergence on $(0,\infty)$, the weaker statement is enough *because continuity is a local property.* Namely, you only need uniform convergence on *some* interval $(x_0-\varepsilon, x_0+\varepsilon)$ around $x_0>0$ to show continuity at $x_0$. And you have that by taking $a=\frac{x_0}{2}$.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I, I notice that difference between the family of closed intervals and (0,\infty). But what about the statement "for all x>0", how does that  compare to "on (0,\infty)" for example? Which of these statements imply the others. Is it possible to generalize the three statements I mentioned to other cases than series? Thanks

Comment: Look at my edit: this does cover, I believe, your later $\forall x>0$ question. Namely, you want to show that some local property (continuity, differentiability, you name it) holds at every $x>0$. This will follow by the weak statement "uniform convergence of the series on every $[a,b]$, since then you have in particular uniform convergence on $[x/2, 3x/2]$ for any fixed $x>0$. (So you have, say, continuity of the limiting function on $[x/2, 3x/2]$, and therefore at $x$ -- this being for every $x>0$.)

Answer (score 1):

The statement

$$\forall a > 0\colon f_n \text{ converges uniformly to } f \text{ on } [a,\infty)$$

is different than the statement

$$f_n \text{ converges uniformly to } f \text{ on } (0,\infty)$$

For example, let $f_n(x) = 1/(nx)$. Let $a>0$. Then $f_n(x)\leq 1/(na)$ for all $x\geq 0$. Therefore, letting $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary, we can pick $n$ large enough to ensure $\sup_{x\in[a,\infty)}|f_n(x)|<\epsilon$. However, this is not true on $(0,\infty)$.

> What is concerning, however, is that it seems like the lecturer is
>   trying to get you to show that the sequence is not convergent
>   pointwise on $(0,\infty)$. This strikes me as odd since if a sequence
>   converges uniformly on each set of the form $[a,\infty)$, it
>   convergence pointwise on $(0,\infty)$. Perhaps there is a typo there.

Comment: Yes, typo. Is it possible to generalize the three statements I mentioned to other cases than series? It would be great if you could also address the third statement "for all x>0", and perhaps compare it to on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: As for the last statement, it is hard to say. It depends on the property that the lecturer is proving on $[a,b]$. For example, we just saw (above) that something being true on $[a,b]$ for all $a>0$ does not necessarily make it true on $(0,\infty)$.